# How to check if a request is GET or POST in Wicket?

Tags: wicket

Currently I use following way to check if a request is GET or POST in Wicket WebPage:

```
public DummyPage(PageParameters pageParameters) {
    super(pageParameters);

    final WebRequest wr = (WebRequest) getRequest();
    final HttpServletRequest hsr = wr.getHttpServletRequest();
    if (hsr.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("post")) {
    }
}
```

Is there better way to do so?

Comment: Why do you need to know? Wicket abstracts away the HTTP interface so you needn't worry about GET/POST. I would suggest that if you do *need* this detail then maybe you shouldn't be using Wicket

Comment: Just because the business requirement specified it can only accept POST request. It returns error message when receiving GET request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no better way as far as I know. The only way to get access to HttpServletRequest is just the way you do it.
The only improvement you could do is to invert order of equals parameters. You should compare always-not-null value (as contants) with almost-always null value :)

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find a better way. Maybe this is not an issue for most people.